# Mongoose возвращает документ с объектом, а нужно просто объект (метод lean() не помогает)

Tags: javascript, mongodb

Есть метод возвращающий Избранные Офферы:

```
public async getFavorites(req: Request, res: Response) {
    const favoriteOffers = await this.offerService.findFavorites(req.user.id);
    const offers = await Promise.all(favoriteOffers.map(async (favoriteOffer) => {
      const averageRank = await this.offerService.calcRank(String(favoriteOffer._id));

      return {...favoriteOffer, isFavorite: true, rank: averageRank};
    }));

    console.log('offers-------------------', offers );
    this.ok(res, fillDTO(OffersResponse, offers));
}
```

Вот только этот метод возвращает не офферы, а документы из БД с лишними полями.
Вот что в консоли получаю:

```
offers------------------- [
  {
    '$__': InternalCache { activePaths: [StateMachine], skipId: true },
    '$isNew': false,
    _doc: {
      _id: new ObjectId("636026416bdbf41ee96758bb"),
      bedrooms: 7,
      city: [Object],
      ... далее куча разных полей оффера
    },
    isFavorite: true,
    rank: 3
  },
  {
    '$__': InternalCache { activePaths: [StateMachine], skipId: true },
    '$isNew': false,
    _doc: {
      _id: new ObjectId("636026426bdbf41ee9675972"),
      bedrooms: 7,
      city: [Object],
      ... далее куча разных полей оффера
    },
    isFavorite: true,
    rank: 1
  }
]
```

И что самое интересное, точно такой же код для премиальных офферов, у меня работает, а на избранных офферах вылезает вот это вот.
В инете, в том числе и на этом сайте везде советуют использовать метод lean(), чтобы вытащить нужный объект из поля _doc, но у меня не получается. Куда я только не пихал этот lean(), отовсюду меня прогонял ТупСкрипт.
Два часа сижу туплю, уже не знаю что делать.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема была в методе `find()`, который использовался в `this.offerService.findFavorites`.
Заменил его на агрегацию и всё заработало.
Диф изменений на скрине. Может кому-нибудь пригодится мой опыт[image: введите сюда описание изображения].

Comment: [в виде картинки — точно никому не пригодится.](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/12119)

Comment: Почему нет? Главное же понятно, что проблема в методе `find()` и видно как она решается через агрегацию. Не обязательно копипастить мой код один в один. Сложность обычно именно заключается в нахождении причины проблемы. А реализацию решения можно написать без проблем самому.